# failed to put mappings on indices crash the elasticsearch [5.4.1]

Tags: elasticsearch, crash

ElasticSearch [5.4.1]
1 we have the some index like ics_pcs_2017.06.06
2 we delete the some old index use jave code:
    getClient.admin().indices().prepareDelete(indexname).execute().actionGet()

```
I think the index ics_pcs_2017.06.06 will have 60G+ and 100,000,000 documents in it.
```

3 we make a new logstash to receive old logs ,and we found in the ES log:
    ES logs info

```
create index for ics_pcs_2017.06.06( didn't get the detail log)

.....
[o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexservice] create index cause [auto(bulk api)], templates[icstemplate],shards [6]/[1], mappings [icslog]

.....
[o.e.c.m.MetaDataCreateIndexservice] [ics_pcs_2017.06.06/xtNoHLSOS4GBQo01-Nprg] update_mapping [icslog]

...
[o.e.a.a.1.m.p.TransportPutMappingAction] [ics-master1] failed to put mappings on indices[[[ics_pcs_2017.06.06/xtNoHLSOS4GBQo01-Nprg]]]
org.elasticsearch.cluster.metada.ProcessClusterEventTimeoutException:failed to process cluster event(put-mapping) within 30s

....
-----------
then there is many logs like  failed to put mappings on indices[[[ics_pcs_2017.06.06/xtNoHLSOS4GBQo01-Nprg]]]
... failed to put mappings on indices[[[ics_pcs_2017.06.06/xtNoHLSOS4GBQo01-Nprg]]]
...failed to put mappings on indices[[[ics_pcs_2017.06.06/xtNoHLSOS4GBQo01-Nprg]]]

and cause the elasticsearch master down.
```

Would some wone help and explain the reason, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Such error takes place when there is error while  mapping to fields of given document.
Like for ES-5.4 one of instance:- 
This happens when you try to map 'string'  as in ES vocab 'string' is known as 'keyword'.
More about this article

[Mapping change](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/breaking_50_mapping_changes.html)

In your case, server is first trying to do the mapping,  while in process of try, it is giving timeout message too.

My suggestion : fix the mapping and analyzer  issue .